# Demonstrate that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\sin(nx) ~ dx = 0 $ for $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}).$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lp-spaces

We will first demonstrate that this holds for step functions. Let, $\phi = \mathcal{X}_{(a,b)}$ where $a < b$. Now,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi \sin(nx) ~ dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int^{b}_{a}\sin(nx) dx = 0.$$
The last statement can be obtained via direct computation of the integral. Let, $\varphi = \sum^{N}_{j=1}c_j\mathcal{X}_{I_j}$ where $I_j$ is an interval for $j \in [1,N]$. Using additivity of integral, we obtain:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi \sin(nx)~dx = 0. $$
We know that step functions are dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Hence, there exists a sequence of step functions $\{\varphi_k\}_{k \ge 1}$ such that:
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left\lVert f - \varphi_k\right\rVert_{1}  = 0.$$
Hence,
$$|\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\sin(nx)~ dx | \le |\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\sin(nx)~ dx  - \int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi_k\sin(nx)~ dx  | + |\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi_k\sin(nx)~ dx |.$$
Then,
$$ |\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\sin(nx)~ dx | \le \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)-\varphi_k(x)| dx +|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi_k\sin(nx)~ dx |.$$
First take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ with respect to the previous inequality and we obtain:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\sin(nx)~ dx | \le \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)-\varphi_k(x)| dx.$$
Then we take the limit as $k \rightarrow \infty$ with respect to the previous inequality and then we obtain:
$$  \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\sin(nx)~ dx | \le 0 \implies \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\sin(nx)~ dx | \le 0.$$

Does my proof look good? I'm wondering if the last implication in my proof is valid?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically correct. Perhaps, you may use $\varepsilon>0$ and $\limsup$ to eliminate ambiguity.

For any $\varepsilon >0$, there exists a step function $\varphi$ such that $\|f-\varphi\|<\varepsilon$. Then,
$$
\left |\int_{\mathbb{R}}f \sin (nx)\, dx \right |\leq  \ \|f-\varphi\|+\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi\sin(nx)\, dx \right | < \varepsilon + \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi\sin(nx)\, dx \right |
$$

Taking $n \to \infty$ implies
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\left |\int_{\mathbb{R}}f \sin (nx)\, dx \right | \leq \varepsilon
$$

Since $\varepsilon>0$ can be arbitrary number, we conclude

$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\left |\int_{\mathbb{R}}f \sin (nx)\, dx \right | =0.
$$

Comment: I see thanks for the input. I was wondering why one would use lim sup in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: We use $\limsup$ when the existence of the limit is not proven yet but want to bound the behavior in $n \to \infty$. In this case, you want to get the upper bound of the integral when $n \to \infty$.

Comment: To be specific, it is problematic to introduce $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \int_\mathbb{R} f\sin(nx)\, dx \right|$ before the existence of the limit is assured, so you should have used $\limsup$ instead in your proof.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Never realized that, but it makes sense.

Comment: $\limsup$ is very useful in doing this kind of proof, so you should become comfortable using it.